# How to open a local (inside the extension package) file in a vscode extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a vscode extension. I want to provide a `help` command which, when invoked, opens a `help.md` file that is provided by the extension and therefore, I assume, shipped as part of the extension package.

```
myext/
├── .vscode/
├── test/
├── package.json
├── extension.js
├── help.md
```

How can I get a reference to the extension package content and open file `help.md` in the editor where the extension is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path to any file in your extension using the extension context. Here's a function I use [in my extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) to [determine the absolute path](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/FrontendUtils.ts#L23) to files I want to load:

```
/**
 * Returns the absolute path to a file located in our misc folder.
 *
 * @param file The base file name.
 * @param context The context of this extension to get its path regardless where it is installed.
 * @param webview When given format the path for use in this webview.
 */
public static getMiscPath(file: string, context: ExtensionContext, webView?: Webview): string
{
    if (webView) {
        let uri = Uri.file(context.asAbsolutePath(path.join('misc', file)));
        return webView.asWebviewUri(uri).toString();
    }
    return context.asAbsolutePath(path.join('misc', file));
}
```

This function determines 2 different variants of the path:

1. w/o WebView instance: just the absolute file path on disk.
2. with WebView instance: a web URL for use in HTML/CSS.